# Finding a memory leak in java restful api

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, memory-leaks, java-memory-leaks

Im an amateur programming ambitious to learn, but I've encountered a new type of problem that I don't even know where to begin to look - memory leaks in java. I've searched around and can't really find anything that would help me. I used Tomcat v9.0 and Java 1.8. I don't even know what code you need to see in order to help.

**I get this warning when im trying to send a request to my REST api**

```
VARNING: The web application [School] appears to have started a thread named [pool-2-thread-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(Unknown Source)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(Unknown Source)
 java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(Unknown Source)
 java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(Unknown Source)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(Unknown Source)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The server can work for one or two requests then it just stops. Since im new to this type of problem I have no idea what might cause it, and searching around didn't really help me in my amateurish ways. I'm guessing however that im creating threads in some way but they're not being closed.

**The controller i tried to reach with a get method**

```
package se.consys.controllers;

import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status;
import javax.persistence.NoResultException;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.DELETE;
import javax.ws.rs.DefaultValue;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.PATCH;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import se.consys.Entities.Course;
import se.consys.Entities.Lecture;
import se.consys.Entities.Student;
import se.consys.Entities.Teacher;
import se.consys.Utilities.HibernateUtility;
import se.consys.dataaccess.DaoGenericHibernateImpl;
import se.consys.params.LocalDateParam;
import se.consys.params.LocalDateTimeParam;
import se.consys.params.MapHelper;
import se.consys.services.GenericService;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes, unchecked")
@Path("courses")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class CourseController {

    private GenericService courseService = GenericService.getGenericService(new DaoGenericHibernateImpl<>(Course.class));
    private GenericService teacherService = GenericService.getGenericService(new DaoGenericHibernateImpl<>(Teacher.class));
    private GenericService studentService = GenericService.getGenericService(new DaoGenericHibernateImpl<>(Student.class));
    private String noCourseFoundMsg = "No course found with the specified id.";


    @GET
    public Response getAll() {
        List<Course> courses = courseService.findAll();
        return Response.status(200).build();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/{id}")
    public Response getById(@PathParam("id") int id) {
        try {
            Course course = (Course) courseService.findById(id);
            return Response.ok().entity(course).build();
        } catch (NoResultException e) {
            System.out.println(noCourseFoundMsg);
            return Response.status(204).build();
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @POST
    public Response create(Course entity) {
        courseService.create(entity);
        return Response.status(201).entity(entity).build();
    }

    @PATCH
    @Path("/{id}")
    public Response partialUpdate(@DefaultValue("0") @PathParam("id") int id, 

            @DefaultValue("null") @QueryParam("name") String courseName,
            @DefaultValue("-1") @QueryParam("duration") int durationInMonths,
            @DefaultValue("") @QueryParam("end") LocalDateParam endDate,
            @DefaultValue("") @QueryParam("start") LocalDateParam startDate,
            @DefaultValue("") @QueryParam("timestamp") LocalDateTimeParam timeStamp,
            @DefaultValue("-1") @QueryParam("supervisor") int supervisor)
            {
        Course courseToBeUpdated = (Course) courseService.findById(id); 
        System.out.println(courseName);
        if (courseName != null) courseToBeUpdated.setCourseName(courseName);
        if (durationInMonths != -1) courseToBeUpdated.setDurationInMonths(durationInMonths);
        if (endDate != null && !endDate.getLocalDate().equals(LocalDate.MIN)) courseToBeUpdated.setEndDate(endDate.getLocalDate());
        if (startDate != null && !startDate.getLocalDate().equals(LocalDate.MIN)) courseToBeUpdated.setStartDate(startDate.getLocalDate());
        if (timeStamp != null && !timeStamp.getLocalDateTime().equals(LocalDateTime.MIN)) courseToBeUpdated.setTimeStamp(timeStamp.getLocalDateTime());
        if (supervisor != -1) courseToBeUpdated.setSupervisor((Teacher) teacherService.findById(supervisor));

        courseService.update(courseToBeUpdated);
        return Response.status(200).build();
    }

    @PATCH
    @Path("/{id}/students")
    public Response partialUpdateOnStudents(
            @DefaultValue("0") @PathParam("id") int id,
            @DefaultValue("null") @QueryParam("update") String studentString) {
        String[] seperatedIds = studentString.split("-");
        List<Integer> studentIds = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < seperatedIds.length; i++) {
            studentIds.add((int) Integer.parseInt(seperatedIds[i]));
        }

        List<Student> allStudents = studentService.findAll();
        List<Student> StudentsToAddIntoCourse = new ArrayList<Student>();
        for (int i = 0; i < allStudents.size(); i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < studentIds.size(); j++) {
                if (allStudents.get(i).getId() == studentIds.get(j)) {
                    StudentsToAddIntoCourse.add(allStudents.get(i));
                }
            }
        }

        Course courseToBeUpdated = (Course) courseService.findById(id);
        if (studentString != null) courseToBeUpdated.setStudents(StudentsToAddIntoCourse);
        courseService.update(courseToBeUpdated);

        return Response.status(200).build();
    }

    @PUT
    @Path("/{id}")
    public Response update(@DefaultValue("0") @PathParam("id") int id, Course entity) {
        try {
            Course courseToBeUpdated = (Course) courseService.findById(id);
            courseToBeUpdated.setCourseName(entity.getCourseName());
            courseToBeUpdated.setDurationInMonths(entity.getDurationInMonths());
            courseToBeUpdated.setEndDate(entity.getEndDate());
            courseToBeUpdated.setScheduledLectures(entity.getScheduledLectures());
            courseToBeUpdated.setStartDate(entity.getStartDate());
            courseToBeUpdated.setStudents(entity.getStudents());
            courseToBeUpdated.setSupervisor(entity.getSupervisor());
            courseToBeUpdated.setTimeStamp(entity.getTimeStamp());
            courseService.update(courseToBeUpdated);
            return Response.status(200).entity(entity).build();
        } catch (NoResultException e) {
            System.out.println(noCourseFoundMsg);
            return Response.ok().status(204).build();
        }
    }

    @DELETE
    @Path("/{id}")
    public Response delete(@DefaultValue("0") @PathParam("id") int id) {
        try {
            Course courseToBeDeleted = (Course) courseService.findById(id);
            courseService.delete(courseToBeDeleted);
            return Response.status(200).build();
        } catch (NoResultException e) {
            System.out.println(noCourseFoundMsg);
            return Response.status(204).build();
        } 
    }
}
```

I have a suspicion that the problem actually is my generic dao and dao service that probably is completely wrong but works on paper. Im new to generics and managed to throw something together.

**DaoGenericHibernateImpl**

```
package se.consys.dataaccess;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;

import se.consys.Utilities.Helper;
import se.consys.Utilities.HibernateUtility;
import se.consys.services.GenericService;

public class DaoGenericHibernateImpl<T extends Serializable> implements IGenericDao<T> {

    Session session = HibernateUtility.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    private String activeClassName;
    private String wrongClassError = "ERROR: Wrong class used on the established service.";

    public DaoGenericHibernateImpl(Class<T> type) {
        activeClassName = type.getSimpleName();
    }

    @Override
    public void create(T entity) {
        if (entity.getClass().getSimpleName().equals(activeClassName)) {
            session.beginTransaction();
            session.persist(entity);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } else {
            System.out.println(wrongClassError + " Entity has not been saved to the database. "
                + "Class used: " + entity.getClass().getSimpleName() + ". "
                + "Class expected: " + activeClassName + ".");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public T update(T entity) {
        if (entity.getClass().getSimpleName().equals(activeClassName)) {
            session.beginTransaction();
            session.merge(entity);  
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            return entity;
        } else {
            System.out.println(wrongClassError + " Entity has not been updated. "
                + "Class used: " + entity.getClass().getSimpleName() + ". "
                + "Class expected: " + activeClassName + ".");
        }
        return entity;
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(T entity) {
        if (entity.getClass().getSimpleName().equals(activeClassName)) {
            session.beginTransaction();
            //session.update(entity);
            session.delete(entity);

            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } else {
            System.out.println(wrongClassError + " Entity has not been deleted. "
                + "Class used: " + entity.getClass().getSimpleName() + ". "
                + "Class expected: " + activeClassName + ".");
        }       
    }

    @Override
    public T findById(int id) {
        final String HQL_BY_ID = "FROM " + activeClassName + " WHERE id=:id";

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        T result = (T) session.createQuery(HQL_BY_ID)
            .setParameter("id", id)
            .setMaxResults(1)
            .getSingleResult();     
        return  result;
    }

    @Override
    public List<T> findAll() {
        String HQL_FIND_ALL = "FROM " + activeClassName;

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<T> result = (List<T>) session.createQuery(HQL_FIND_ALL)
            .getResultList();
        return  result;
    }

    @Override
    public void removeReference(T entity, Class<?> reference) {
        Method setter = Helper.findSetter(entity, reference);
        try {
            setter.invoke(entity, null);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

I feel like i can just keep adding codeblocks so ill add a link to my [github](https://github.com/Nossra/School) where everything is, hope that is ok.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: That is *really* a lot of code. Did you have to include commented-out code?

Comment: Not really. I edited it out now. Sorry but as i said i don't really know what you need to see.

Comment: Try to eliminate the issue, after what type of requests ur tomcat starts to have memory leak, you mentioned after 2 requests, what requests are these (create, update, findAll ... ) ?

Answer (score 0):

In general, the first thing you need to think about in this case is that if you can't reason about the memory safety and/or thread safety of your code then you've actually got two problems to solve.

In terms of what you're actually seeing, what you need are the standard tools for identifying what threads are running and what memory is in use. You can find out what threads are running with a tool like jconsole (GUI) or jstack (CLI). They're both included as a standard part of the JDK and will give you a stack trace of all the threads running in the system. They won't necessarily tell you *why* those threads exist, but the stack traces themselves may help you identify where they're coming from.

The problem you're describing sounds like a runaway thread although it could *also* be memory related, and the error message suggests that's a likely root cause, so it may also be useful to look into the memory usage. For that, you can also use jconsole (profile section) or jhat & jmap (if you're a CLI-fan). Either of those will tell you what objects exist in the VM heap and what type they are. This information can be incredibly useful but also incredibly distracting - most heaps are dominated by Strings, Maps and Lists, because that's what most programs are built out of. Still, you can often gain useful insights by comparing the difference between two profiles, one taken when 'everything seems fine' and one taken when 'its stopped working'.

Those sorts of tools can help you identify a problem in a running system. Once you've done that you probably want to look at why it wasn't clear from the program text that there was going to be a thread-pool or memory usage issue. Things like using a Map as a cache is a big one. Or implementing equals/hashcode in terms of mutable fields. For threads, anything which may not terminate can jam up a thread pool pretty quickly - blocking IO in a web-server (for example).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write such a long answer. I tried and started with the JConsole to look at the heap and the threads. But the moment the server stopped working there wasnt a peak in either of them. I had 35 threads which peaked on 39 at some point but not when it stopped working. The heap shifted like normally between 20 to 50 MB.